# Memoize entire block / anonymous function cleanly in Python

Tags: python, anonymous-function, memoization

What's the cleanest way (from user's side) to memoize an entire block of computation (a multi-line lambda, if those were possible to create) in Python?

With memoize I intend a generic "If the result was already computed, just load it from somewhere. Otherwise compute it and save it somewhere."

My current solution (for writing something that caches to disk the result of arbitrary computations) is:

1. Have one decorator that does the caching (it takes the file name where to save/load as parameter):

```py
from functools import wraps

def disk_cache(filename):
    def decorator(compute_result_func):
        @wraps(compute_result_func) # don't shadow function's docstring
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            if not os.path.exists(filename):
                # compute and save
                print "compute"
                result = compute_result_func()
                print "save"
                pickle.dump(result, open(filename, 'wb'))
            else:
                # load
                print "load"
                result = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
            return result
        return wrapped
    return decorator
```

2. Whenever I have a block of computations I would like to memoize, I wrap it into a function with a generic name (I would use a multi-line lambda if I could) that takes nothing (just captures variables that are in the larger scope) and returns a single result. I decorate this function with my decorator, and I immediately call the function.

```py
@disk_cache(filename='/path/to/dump.pkl')
def multi_line_lambda():
    # do some stuff
    x = 2 ** 2
    y = 7
    return x + y
multi_line_lambda()
```

Is it possible to use a pattern which is syntactically cleaner? Something like

```py
with cache(filename):
    do x
    do y
    return result # which is actually just loaded if already existing
```

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you define a function? The fact that you want to do the same calculation later screams out for a function.

Comment: Because as in the example I might simply have a block of code which exists just in one script, but it might perform heavy computations. Therefore it might be useful to have the old results stored on disk, so to load them next time I work on this script. Maybe 'memoize' isn't the right word. 'Caching to disk' could better describe my need.

Comment: OK, you're thinking of this as an on-going interactive session that might be interrupted, whereas I'm thinking in terms of a self-contained script.

Answer (score 0):

I explored this exact question in the past (shameless plug: here is [my result](https://github.com/CMUSTRUDEL/strudel.utils/blob/master/stutils/decorators.py)) and found it's better to use your existing approach. However, if you are willing to abuse Python syntax, here is how you can do it:

```
def disk_cache(filename):
    def decorator(compute_result_func):
        if not os.path.exists(filename):
            result = compute_result_func()
            pickle.dump(result, open(filename, 'wb'))
        else:
            result = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
        return result
    return decorator
```

Now,

```
@disk_cache(filename='/path/to/dump.pkl')
def calculated_stuff():
    # do some stuff
    x = 2 ** 2
    y = 7
    return x + y
# at this point, calculated_stuff() already contains the result (11)
```

Please, remember it is a dirty practice. Don't do it in code somebody else can read

Comment: Your link is broken. If I understand correctly, the solution you are suggesting differs from mine just in the fact that mine is lazily evaluated/cached, while yours is computed at function's definition time. Is that right? If this is the case, I don't see one solution being better than the other. When you need evaluation-at-definition-time you can use yours, otherwise the other.

Comment: by "my solution" I mean the one by the link (fixed). Your understanding the one here is evaluated at the definition time is correct. My understanding is you're looking for a concise definition of cached blocks, and this one indeed saves the actual call to a function. Otherwise, it is dirty and should never be used.